# Multi Tenant authentication middleware

Tags: security, asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver4

Im looking for the best approach for supporting multi-tenancy when your identity server has a URL per tenant. This is a problem for me because im using the [aspnet/security](https://github.com/aspnet/Security) middleware and you obviously need to set the token endpoint etc at startup. Im effectively looking to resolve the host at runtime.

[image: Example]

I'm hoping its already a solved problem. If not im thinking of just creating an abstraction around this middleware and hook into the oAuth event [RedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/Events/OAuthEvents.cs#L39) and resolve my host at that point. Think I will also have to create my own backchannel handler?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to write this one yourself, as I've not seen anything like that out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @trailmax thats what I ended up doing